# Wire a form html element of type object to a state objet in react

Tags: reactjs

I have two form elements which come under the same array

```
<div className="form-group">
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="user[username]"
              value={this.state.user.username}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              placeholder="Customer Name"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="user[mobilenumber]"
              value={this.state.user.mobilenumber}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              placeholder="Customer mbole no."
            />
          </div>
```

In the constructor i am declaring the state as follows

```
this.state = {
  user: { username: "", mobilenumber: "" },
  clothname: "",
  description: "",
  errors: {}
};
```

But on changing the values in the form for user[username] and user[mobilenumber] the entered values are not getting populated in the state object user. While it works for the other two state variables 'cloth' and 'description'. They have simple name attribute like 'clothname'.

And the onChange method

```
onChange(event) {
this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}
```

Comment: can you post `onChange` method

Comment: updated onChange method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React updated the dom only when it is able to  detects changes. `this.state.user` is a object. When you are changing a property of `this.state.user`, its reference doesn't change and so react thinks that user object is not modified and does not updates the DOM.

Solution is to update the object completely.

```
onChange(e) {
    let state = {..this.state};
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
}

// I prefer this one
onUserChange(e) {
    let user = {...this.state.user};
    user[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ user });
}
```

Comment: Got you. I have to give away the name=user[username] and user[mobilenumber] from the html elements and make them simple like username and mobilenumber. Also associate the elements with the different method-onUserChange. Let me try that. I was hoping if any way to change the "name" attribute of the html element so that same onChange() will accomodate it.

Comment: @piyesh-kumar your suggestion worked. Still can you think of any way to manipulate the "name" attribute of the html element so that the change can be accommodated in the same onChange method.